# IE10 - base64-encoded image load error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

After uploading 10-20 images (~2MB, one by one in the synchronous loop) IE throws an error during loading the image from base64 string. I have in my code something like this:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function () { console.log('onload'); /* some simple work with canvas */ };
  img.onerror = function () { console.log('onerror'); };
  img.src = e.target.result;
};
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

IE throws an error after some time and do not want to load more images. I have tried to use `setTimeout` but without success.

Any ideas why it happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers can have some limitation on data URI size

Try the `URL.createObjectURL` instead

```
var src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () { 
    /* some simple work with canvas */ };
    URL.revokeObjectURL(src); 
    console.log('onload');
img.onerror = function () { console.log('onerror'); };
img.src = src;
```